# Blackberry 10 launch wifi settings page programmatically

Tags: blackberry, wifi, blackberry-10

In my blackberry 10 (QNX, Cascades) application I have to launch WIFI setting page programmatically. I google it but having no luck.

Please help me to find out is it possible in Blackberry 10 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's undocumented and you won't find any information on Google. Here's how to do it :

```
bb::system::InvokeRequest request;
request.setUri("settings://wifi");

bb::system::InvokeManager manager;
manager.invoke(request);
```

The magic string is `settings://wifi`, you can try it right inside your BlackBerry 10 browser to see where it will send you, just note that the BlackBerry 10 browser will have an additional popup asking if you want to open the URI, this popup won't show in your application it will open the Settings app as a card at the Wi-Fi page directly. User can then just dismiss the card to get back to your app.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thank you Roger!